# Selenium, Xpath, StoreText of the next sibling by ID of the first

Tags: selenium, xpath, html-table

Today I discovered selenium so I am eager to put it to use.

I was just writing a script for a webpage of a web based game, and I can store the text in a table I want to by putting the exact Xpath, but I would like to store it based off the ID name of the `<th>` tag before it in this example the ID being credits.

Here is the web page code.

```
<table class="no_back" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="credits" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <th>41</th>
            <th id="board">
            <th>0 New</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So 41 would be the value I want to store, I can access the credits ID simple enough using:

```
xpath=id('credits')
```

But when I try to put the /th[2] or such it wont work. I am very new to the whole Xpath thing also so any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To select particular node you can use

```
//table[@class="header_completed"]/following-sibling::table[@align="center"][1]/preceding-sibling::table[preceding-sibling::table[@class="header_completed"]]
```

for siblings and preceding-siblings.

First I navigate to the **table** with `@class="header_completed"`. From there I select the first following sibling table with `@align="center"`. From there I select all **preceding sibling** tables that have a preceding sibling which is the table with `@class="header_completed"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid...

I found it by looking into xpath rather than Selenium.

```
xpath=id('credits')/following-sibling::th[1]
```

This is the code I used, sorry for wasting anyone's time.